# How to open a new Window (not tab) in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I know that $window.open() opens a new tab with the url specified but is there a way to open a new Window? Did some digging around and couldn't find anything.

Comment: Whether a tab or a window opens is up to the browser (or the user's preferences).

Comment: It's actually not, I figured out how to open a tab AND/OR a window. To open a tab, you'd use $window.open(url). To open a new window, you'd use $window.open(url, window name, attribute, attribute).

Comment: [Don't force me to open a new window](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.open#Usability_issues).

Comment: Blackhole, totally understand the article and i agree with it to the fullest extent but unfortunately the assignment is to "open a new window" and not a tab. Great advice though thank you

Comment: I stand corrected. I wonder, though, whether the assignment author intended to be so explicit.

Comment: isherwood, surprisingly it was. I did the assignment and turned it in as a checkpoint to get some feedback. One of the comments was, "user might not recognize that it's a new page since most users will have some type of dementia. Please make it even more obvious, maybe something that pops out at the user like opening up a new window". Although I thought opening a new tab was sufficient, it wasn't

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using the third parameter of [window.open method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp), you get a window.

Exemple :

```
window.open('http://www.stackoverflow.com', '_blank', 'width=500, height=400')
```